# CSS : Trying to get to div one after another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First div is navbar and I am creating with the help of `twitter-bootstrap`. It has `90px height`.
Rest of the height will taken by another div with an image background. Here is the code for first nav bar div:

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="./index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div id="secondDiv" class="invite-bg">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
      Fluid 6
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**First Div CSS:**

```
.navbar {
  *position: relative;
  *z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 5.7em; /*change*/
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

**Second Div CSS:**

```
div.invite-bg {
    background-image:url('../img/b1g.jpg');
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am facing following issues:

1. How put second div after navbar without using `<br/>`?
2. Second Div is overlapping first Div. I want to divide them with height 30% and 70%.
3. What size of background should choose so that it can fit second div perfectly?

Comment: what do you mean by putting the second div after the navbar? your second div is nested within your navbar div. So either move it out, or use position:absolute to position it where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.invite-bg {
    background-image:url('../img/b1g.jpg');
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;/*moves the div down 30% from the top of the screen*/
}
```

The added `top: 30%;` attribute should work for what I think you are asking.